# Get the part of the string up to the second to last occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below strings

```
'HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3_HOLA4'
'HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3_HOLA4_HOLA5'
```

How could I get the part of the string up to the second to last occurrence of the '_' character?

Expected result:

```
'HOLA1_HOLA2'
'HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3'
```

Comment: Regex replace `_[^_]*_[^_]*$` with an empty string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your duplicate was _wrong_ ... the OP wants the _first_ two path components, not the last ones.  Also, unless your duplicate were for Oracle SQL, then it was probably also too broad.

Comment: It was not a problem at all since the regex could be used with regexp_replace, this hint is in the comment. `regexp_replace(col, '_[^_]*_[^_]*$', '')` [solves it](https://regex101.com/r/x6aNyE/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple (fast) string functions and find the substring up to the second-to-last underscore (rather than using (slow) regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '_', -1, 2) - 1) AS first_part
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3_HOLA4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3_HOLA4_HOLA5' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIRST_PART |
| --- |
| HOLA1_HOLA2 |
| HOLA1_HOLA2_HOLA3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r9dELzb1)

Answer (score -2):

Regarding a regular expression with this behaviour:
You can use a lookahead to get the expected Result

`.*(?=_)`

A lookahead is a zero length assertion (is not included in the match) that asserts that a match has to be followed by the given expression ( `_` in this case). By default regex does a greedy match, therefore the lookahead targets the last underscore in the given text.
Try it here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Vnz3YL/1)

Comment: You cannot use look-ahead as Oracle does not support look-ahead in regular expressions.